# unable to invoke ahref from jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to invoke href link from javascript. Basically it is a logout link. I am trying to invoke this link via jquery model basically it should mimic the link of logout and should redirect the user to login page

`<a id="logout_id" href="${contextPath}/app/logOut" class="nav">logout</a>`

I tried below options but none of them worked

```
function logout(){
    alert('invoked logout' + document.getElementById('logout_id'));
    document.getElementById('logout_id').click();
     $('#logout_id').click(function () {
    alert('clickced');
     });
    //$('#logout_id').get(0).click();
    $('#logout_id').click();
    $('#logout_id').trigger("click");
    $('#logout_id')[0].click();
    $('#logout_id').get(0).click();
    //$('#logout_id').simulate('click');
    $('#logout_id')[0].trigger('click');
    $('#logout_id').triggerHandler('click');
    $('#logout_id').trigger('click');
};
```

Could any one point me what am i doing wrong??

Comment: Why don't you just try `window.location.assign(<pathtologin>)`?

Comment: I suspect `href="${contextPath}/app/logOut"` will literally take you to the page '${contextPath}/app/logOut'

Comment: thank you Amit and Isaac.. window.location = document.getElementById('logout_id').href; worked for me

Comment: try on pageload `$(function(){   $('#logout_id').on('click', function(e){ ... }  });`  for add event on element & call `.trigger('click')` in ur function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set window.location.

```
window.location = document.getElementById('logout_id').href;
```

In your answer, you post that you've used

```
$('#logout_id')[0].click();
```

That should work iirc, so hints that your URL could be bad, I see it's not a static string.

Comment: window.location worked.. but $('#logout_id')[0].click() did not work. I am not using explicit url, on logout it is already working.. what is not clear to me is when i simulate click on logout it is not doing anything.